# Setting up High Availability on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, load-balancing, high-availability, azure-virtual-machine

We are in the process of moving our current IAAS solution over to azure where we host asp.net LOB web applications in IIS with an SQL Server backend.

I’m looking into availability sets. I stumbled upon this article at: http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/understanding_configuring_availability_sets_powershell/

[image: High Available Setup]

This seems like how we want to setup our deployment on Azure where the “Web Servers” are our virtual machines. My question relates to how we setup our virtual machines. Currently we have about 200 separate hosted customers on our IAAS solution which means 200 separate web applications in IIS. With a highly available deployment should the Virtual machines be exact replica’s of each other i.e. 200 customers on box 1 and that again on box 2. Or should we spread them over multiple boxes i.e. 0-50 customers on box 1, 50-100 customers on box 2 and so on.

I cant see how the 2nd option spread would work in a highly available set because if 1 box goes down than all the customers on it go down with it?

Little confused, hoping someone has got advice on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to duplicate everything, the azure load balancer (layer 4 balancer) ensures that load is spread across listening endpoints evenly and randomly, so you cannot know which server will answer a request, hence you must have the same configuration on both boxes. Here is some info on the Azure load balancer which you might find interesting, [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/08/microsoft-azure-load-balancing-services/)

Also put them into an [availability set](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-manage-availability/) so if one of the vm dies for some reason or during updates (which can happen from time to time with vms) you can be sure that at least one of your vms will always be online. You may need more than two vms, it really depends on the amount of traffic each of your clients generate and the load that that creates. But do have atleast two vms.

Just a side note if you haven't used Azure before; it may take you a bit of time to get the cost per vm right over time, but remember to use the schedule to scale up and down to reduce costs and anticipate load on your vms. Also having 4 smaller vms is better than 2 larger vms from a failure point of view and ultimately cost the same over a month. If one large vm dies, you've lost 50% of your capacity to serve your clients, where as if you lost one smaller vm you've only lost 25%.

Comment: Hi David, awesome post. Question, being we will want to be duplicated, is there a way to easily duplicate the vm's and keep them in sync? Im gathering we could image the vm once setup and copy it across but after that if we need to add to it do we need to go through each of the 2 or more duplicates and update them?

Comment: You can image them with Sysprep, this link should help you out [http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-capture-image- windows-server/] Sysprep can be a bit painful sometimes when it doesn't work out with usernames and passwords, so I've had to go though a setup a few times before I could capture a good reusable image. When you create a new image then you can just start up a new set of vms on your staging deployment on your cloud service, when you're read for the swap, hit the swap button to swap production with staging.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the reply. There was another thing that I needed to factor in which is shared docs. Within the LOB the user can upload a doc which is uploaded to the server. If we are split over multiple servers than this will mean that VM A will hold some docs and if the load balancer pushes the user to VM B for their request than the doc will not exist. Any ideas on how to handle docs/files that need to change in a replicated environment? Thanks

Comment: Sure no problem, the file distribution will need something else and it will need some development to use Azure Blobs or Azure File Service. We have a similar approach were a user uploads a file to our cloud service, the next step is to put them into a blob for access and distribution. We keep track of files, the blobs they have been added to, permissions on the blob and the url to serve them from in our db. The db in Azure SQL, is shared amongst the deployed cloud service vms.